# Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails while updating parent

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like that:

```
CREATE TABLE `testt` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `pacitve` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`,`active`),
  KEY `pid` (`pid`,`pacitve`),
  CONSTRAINT `active_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`pid`, `pacitve`) REFERENCES `testt` (`id`, `active`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

pid stands for parent id

My data is like that:

```
id     pid    active  pactive

1      NULL    0       0

2      1       0       0

3      1       0       0

4      2       0       0
```

When I set active = 1 for id = 1, I get this exception. Why am I getting this error? Delete works fine. My purpose is that when I set active=1 for id=1, all children of id=1 should be updated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you have enforced that (`pid`, `pacitve`) match another record in the same table, so for id 1 you have pid = 1 and pacitve = 0, this is fine because the parent row has active = 0. When you change the parent row there is no longer a corresponding row breaking the integrity of the table.

Even though you have CASCADE options these do not work for foreign keys referencing the same table (it allows you to create it, but does not actually do anything on update or delete). The [documentation states](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html):

> If ON UPDATE CASCADE or ON UPDATE SET NULL recurses to update the same table it has previously updated during the cascade, it acts like RESTRICT. This means that you cannot use self-referential ON UPDATE CASCADE or ON UPDATE SET NULL operations. This is to prevent infinite loops resulting from cascaded updates. A self-referential ON DELETE SET NULL, on the other hand, is possible, as is a self-referential ON DELETE CASCADE. Cascading operations may not be nested more than 15 levels deep.

Also be aware that creating a foreign key that refers to a non unique index is not standard and seems like a fairly bizarre deviation from the standards to me. Nevertheless, again the documentation states:

> InnoDB allows a foreign key constraint to reference a non-unique key. This is an InnoDB extension to standard SQL.

Your whole schema is set up wrong, you don't need to make the foreign key reference active at all, nor do you need to store the state of the parent with the child, this can all be achieved within the select. Your table structure should be:

```
CREATE TABLE `testt` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `pid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `active` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `id` (`id`,`active`),
    KEY `pid` (`pid`,`pacitve`),
    CONSTRAINT `pid_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`pid`) REFERENCES `testt` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Then if you need to know the state of the parent you can just use:

```
SELECT  c.id, c.pid, c.active, p.active AS pactive
FROM    testt c
        LEFT JOIN testt p
            ON c.pid = p.id;
```

**[Example before Update](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ab39/1)**

**[Example after Update](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/641d6/1)**

Comment: This is one high-quality answer! Bravo